# SOAP to XML transformation

Tags: xslt

I am trying to do SOAP to XML transformation in XSLT.

I have a field called "acctCd" which is under "externalIDGroup" which is an array. SO i need to check the field lenth for "acctCd" if it is more then 10 charatcer i need to trim it to 10 character  and if it is less i need to get the valuen as it is. This value can come multiple times.Please let me know where is the issue in my code
INput:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:ClaimsRequest xmlns:ns2="http://example.com">     
            <externalIDGroup>              
               <acctCd>plan1  Options</acctCd>               
            </externalIDGroup>
            <externalIDGroup>                            
               <acctCd>Plan2 Options</acctCd>               
            </externalIDGroup>          
      </ns2:ClaimsRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

XSL Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="dp"
version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
     <ClaimsRequest>    
            <xsl:for-each select="//externalIDGroup"> 
 <xsl:variable name="acCode">
            <xsl:value-of select="acctCd"/>
            </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="acCode1"> 
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($acCode) &gt; 10">          
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($acCode, 1,10)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$acCode"/></xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>   
    </xsl:variable>         
                  <claimDetail>                
                    <accountCode><xsl:value-of select="acctCd1"/></accountCode>                             
                  </claimDetail>
            </xsl:for-each>
      </ClaimsRequest>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Desired output :

<ClaimsRequest>  
   <claimDetail>    
      <accountCode>plan1 Opti</accountCode>      
   </claimDetail>
   <claimDetail>    
      <accountCode>Plan2</accountCode>      
   </claimDetail>
</ClaimsRequest>
```

Comment: What is the logic that turns "plan1  Options" (14 characters) into "plan1 Opti" (10 characters), but "Plan2 Options" (13 characters) into "Plan2" 5 characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand how you derived your desired output from the input. I suspect that all you need to do is :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ClaimsRequest>    
        <xsl:for-each select="//externalIDGroup"> 
            <claimDetail>                
                <accountCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(acctCd, 1, 10)"/>
                </accountCode>                             
            </claimDetail>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ClaimsRequest>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes this is also working fine,Thanks a lot for your help. Closing this by accpeting this answer.